# Enthalpy of a pure substance as a function of T and v

Tags: thermodynamics

Why the enthalpy of a pure substance is considered as a function of P and T, as follow [image]

Is there any reason that enthalpy must be considered as a function of P and T or it is possible that I derive a new relation, for example, h=h(T,v) or h=h(P,v)?

source of image : Borgnakke, C., & Sonntag, R. E. (2012). Fundamentals of Thermodynamics (8th ed.). Wiley.

Comment: No.  There is no reason why it has to.

Comment: So I'm free to express the enthalpy as any function of other thermodynamics properties (even entropy/Gibbs free energy etc) as long as I'm able to relate those properties correctly?

Comment: In my judgment, yes.  Being able to work out how is another story.